# paint not saving to bufferedimage

Tags: java, swing, graphics, bufferedimage

The code below was properly plotting a chart to a `JPanel` when I had all the drawing code inside `paintComponent()`.  But I want to save the result to an image file on the hard drive for use elsewhere.  I therefore moved the drawing code into the `updatePaint()` method and took other steps shown below to draw to a `bufferedimage` first and then have the `bufferedimage` available to print to the `JPanel` and to a saved file.  The problem is that the code below just prints a black `JPanel` instead of the chart that was being painted before I rearranged the code.

**How can I change the code below so that the bufferedimage shows the expected chart, and is properly painted to the JPanel, without interfering with its ability to save to the file?**

```
package somepackage;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ChartPanel extends JPanel {
    private BufferedImage paintImage = new BufferedImage(500, 400, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);

    private double[] values;
    private String[] names;
    private String title;
    private double fac_result;

    public ChartPanel(double[] v, String[] n, String t, double fac_res) {
        names = n;
        values = v;
        title = t;
        fac_result = fac_res;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(paintImage, 0, 0, null);
    }

    // draw painting
    public void updatePaint(){
        Graphics g = paintImage.createGraphics();

        // draw on paintImage using Graphics
        if (values == null || values.length == 0)
            return;
        double minValue = 0;
        double maxValue = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            if (minValue > values[i])
                minValue = values[i];
            if (maxValue < values[i])
                maxValue = values[i];
        }

        Dimension d = getSize();
        int clientWidth = d.width;
        int clientHeight = d.height;
        int barWidth = clientWidth / values.length;

        Font titleFont = new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 20);
        FontMetrics titleFontMetrics = g.getFontMetrics(titleFont);
        Font labelFont = new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 10);
        FontMetrics labelFontMetrics = g.getFontMetrics(labelFont);
        int titleWidth = titleFontMetrics.stringWidth(title);
        int y = titleFontMetrics.getAscent();
        int x = (clientWidth - titleWidth) / 2;
        g.setFont(titleFont);
        g.drawString(title, x, y);

        int top = titleFontMetrics.getHeight();
        int bottom = labelFontMetrics.getHeight();
        if (maxValue == minValue)
            return;
        double scale = (clientHeight - top - bottom) / (maxValue - minValue);
        y = clientHeight - labelFontMetrics.getDescent();
        g.setFont(labelFont);
System.out.println("fac_result in paintComponent() is: "+fac_result);
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        int valueX = i * barWidth + 1;
        int valueY = top;
        int height = (int) (values[i] * scale);
    if (values[i] >= 0)
        valueY += (int) ((maxValue - values[i]) * scale);
    else {
        valueY += (int) (maxValue * scale);
        height = -height;
    }
System.out.println("names["+i+"] is: "+names[i]);
    if((Double.parseDouble(names[i])<=(fac_result+0.5))&&(Double.parseDouble(names[i])>=(fac_result-0.5))){
        g.setColor(Color.cyan);
        g.fillRect(valueX, valueY, barWidth - 2, height);
        System.out.println("condition met.");
    }
    else{
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(valueX, valueY, barWidth - 2, height);
    }
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawRect(valueX, valueY, barWidth - 2, height);
    if(i%5==0){
        int labelWidth = labelFontMetrics.stringWidth(names[i]);
        x = i * barWidth + (barWidth - labelWidth) / 2;
        g.drawString(names[i], x, y);
    }
    }
///////////     
    g.dispose();
    // repaint panel with new modified paint
    repaint();
}

public void save() throws IOException{
    ImageIO.write(paintImage, "PNG", new File("C:\\Temp\\filename.png"));
}

public void load() throws IOException {
    paintImage = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Temp\\filename.png"));
    // update panel with new paint image
    repaint();
}

}
```

Note: The above code is called from another class using the following line:

```
new ChartPanel(values, names, label, fac_result));
```

Comment: Try calling `updatePaint` when `invalidate` is called or when the data is changed and BEFORE you write the image :P

Comment: I don't recall suggesting that you should add it anywhere near `paintComponent`.  Override `invalidate` (make sure you call `super.invalidate()` and call `updatePaint()`.  When `save` is called, I'd also recommend calling `updatePaint`, but that's just me

Comment: just to/about your topics == "paint not saving to bufferedimage", I'm sure :-) Thread.sleep() is relevant only to linked thread, missing the significance in your comment because code is in SSCCE/MCVE form, short, runnable, compilable, without guessing:-)  important (for you) is idea int the last 5-8 code lines,

Comment: Every time you update the image, you need to clear the Graphics context first, otherwise you'd just be painting over what was previously there

Comment: Off the top of my head if you set the color to a transparent color it should clear it to a transparent image

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).  Voting to close for lack of one.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To update the state of the `BufferedImage`, you could check to see if `paintImage` is `null` and create and render it when `paintComponent` is called.
2. Just like any painting, you have to clear the `Graphics` context before painting to it.  From memory, set the color to a transparent color and use `clearRect` to clear the contents back to a transparent state before you paint it.